# Extracting ListView Values

Tags: vb.net

How to extract a cell value from a Listview.
    strName = ListView1.Items(0).SubItems(9).Text
works but sometimes get errors like InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index' or Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Since the users are not at the same location I am unable to recreate these errors.

Comment: If there are no items, you'll get the NRE, check the count first.

Comment: Thank you. There will be always only one row (Selecting the Top 1 from the database and populating the listview) Users will not proceed without one.(Button is not enabled if there are no item) It works fine for me and it drives me crazy why sometimes it doesn't work for others.

Comment: The only way *that* line of code can throw an NRE is if there is no Item or that LVI has no subitems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem. You must add an If statement to check that there is at least one selected item and only try to access it if there is.

```
If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
StrName = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(9).Text
End If
```

Comment: Thank you Noidea. There will be only one row and users cannot proceed without it. I was considering this option but wondering will it get deselected in anyway.

Comment: Anyway, with this code you won't get the "traditional" error. If you somehow find a way to do it properly, mark as answered.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the ListView1.items.count >0 or ListView1.selectedItems.Count > 0

Comment: Update: There was another issue If ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(9).Text = "BDMS" Or ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(9).Text = "BDBR" Then fails. Assigning to a variable Var1 = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(9).Text and then checking if var1="BRMS" or var1 = "BDBR" Then - works.

Comment: i'm sorry i couldn't understand. did you figure out why?